# how to make several arrays by merging two other ones

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hope doing well.
Is it possible to merge two big numpy array to make a several ones. These two arrays have the same number of rows. One array contains some names:

```
name_arr = [[sub_1],
            [sub_2],
            [sub_3],
              ...
            [sub_n]]
```

The other one has some values:

```
value_arr = [[1, 2, 3],
             [5, 2, -1],
             [0, 0, 4],
              ...
             [6, 18,200]]
```

Now, I want to extract numpy arrays using both the `name_arr` and `value_arr`. To be clear, I want to extract arrays with the names coming from `name_arr` and values coming from `value_arr`:

```
sub_1= [[1, 2, 3]]

sub_2= [[1, 2, 3]]

sub_3= [[0, 0, 4]]

...

sub_4= [[6, 18,200]]
```

I tried to use a for loop, but it was not successful:

```
for i in name_arr:
    for j in value_arr:
        if i == j:
            name_arr [0, i] = value_arr [0, j]
```

but it was not successful at all ...
FYI, I made the arrays by splitting a dictionary,

```
Dict_data = {'sub_1' : [1, 2, 3],
             'sub_2' : [5, 2, -1], 
             'sub_3' : [0, 0, 4], 
              ... ,
             'sub_n' : [6, 18,200]}
```

in case of having a solution to do my extraction directly from the dictionary, I deeply appreciate that. definitely I prefer to find a was to extract numpy arrays with the name of my keys and related data.
In advance, I appreciate any feedback.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I assume your name array contains strings as follows:

```py
name_arr = ['sub_1',
            'sub_2',
            'sub_3',
              ...
            'sub_n']
```

in this case you can simply do it with a for loop:

```py
my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(name_arr)):
    my_dict[name_arr[i]] = value_arr[i, :]
```

Comment: Dear @fodma1, Thanks for your quick response. In your solution, should I firstly extarct names and values from my dictionar or I can do it directly? I tried it but it is giving me qgain a dictionary having names and values. In fact, I want to export several arrays rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, that's because `name_arr` is not a list of strings - as I assumed. you can only use hashable values as dictionary keys. If you want to use variable names (`[[sub_1]]`)- I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: Aha, But I want to have several arrays. In your solution, again I have a dictionary. Did I explain my problem correctly? thanks for giving time.

Comment: You'll have several arrays, but within the dictionary. You can't programmatically generate multiple variables in Python (at least not that I know of. I think that'd be metaprogramming). If you want to keep the name and the list next to each other you might want to chose a different data structure.

Comment: Aha, good to know. I thought maybe it is possible to export each key (as the name of my array) and value (as the content of array) and make several arrays using a single dictionary.